# Python: Get unbound class method

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can you get a not bound class method?

```
class Foo:
    @classmethod
    def bar(cls): pass

>>> Foo.bar
<bound method type.bar of <class '__main__.Foo'>>
```

Edit: This is python 3.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Did you really mean for `Foo` to be an old-style class here?

Comment: In Python 3, there is no such thing as an unbound method. I'll update my answer, but… it's not as interesting a question.

Comment: Changing the phrase to "not bound class method" doesn't help. There still is no such thing. If you want the bare function itself, my answer already says how to get that. If you want something different, then either you're asking for something that doesn't exist, or you need to explain what exactly you're asking for.

Comment: What do you actually want this thing for? What do you plan to do with it? If you want to make calls on it by passing it an explicit `cls` argument, or create bound methods out of it, or anything else, what you want (in Python 3) is just a plain old function. (And if you want to call it directly, the bound method is already what you want.)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Python 3 does not have unbound methods. Forget about `classmethod`s for a moment, and look at this:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def baz(self): pass
>>> Foo.baz
<function __main__.baz>
```

In 2.x, this would be `<unbound method Foo.baz>`, but 3.x does not have unbound methods.

If you want to get the function out of a bound method, that's easy:

```
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo.baz
<bound method Foo.baz of <__main__.Foo object at 0x104da6850>>
>>> foo.baz.__func__
<function __main__.baz>
```

In the same way:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     @classmethod
...     def bar(cls): pass
>>> Foo.bar
<bound method type.bar of <class '__main__.Foo'>>
>>> Foo.bar.__func__
<function __main__.bar>
```

Things are much more interesting in 2.x, because there actually *are* unbound methods to get. You can't normally see an unbound `classmethod`, because the whole point is that they get bound to the class at class creation time, instead of being left unbound and then bound to each instance at instance creation time.

But really, an unbound method is just any `instancemethod` whose `im_self` is None. So, just as you can do this:

```
class Foo(object):
    def baz(self): pass

foo = Foo()
bound_baz = foo.baz
unbound_baz = new.instancemethod(bound_baz.im_func, None, bound_baz.im_class)
```

Note that `bound_baz.im_func` is the 2.x version of `bound_baz.__func__` in 3.x—but that `new.instancemethod` does not have a 3.x equivalent.

The documentation says that `new` is deprecated in favor of `types`, for 3.x compatibility, and in fact, you can do this in 2.x:

```
unbound_baz = types.MethodType(bound_baz.im_func, None, bound_baz.im_class)
```

But that doesn't work in 3.x, because `MethodType` does not take a `class` parameter, and does not allow its `instance` parameter to be `None`. And personally, when I'm doing something that is explicitly 2.x-only and cannot be ported to 3.x, I think using `new` is clearer.

Anyway, given a class in 2.x, you can do this:

```
class Foo(object):
    @classmethod
    def bar(cls): pass

bound_bar = Foo.bar
unbound_bar = new.instancemethod(bound_bar.im_func, None, bound_bar.im_class)
```

If you print it out, you'll see:

```
<unbound method type.bar>
```

Or, using your example, with an old-style class:

```
class Foo:
    @classmethod
    def bar(cls): pass

<unbound method classobj.bar>
```

And yes, maybe it's a bit of a cheat that the `im_class` of a `classmethod` for an old-style class is `classobj` even though that's not `Foo.__class__`, but it seems like the most reasonable way to get old-style and new-style classes working similarly in all of the usual use cases.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry if my terminology was confusing.  By "unbound" I meant "not bound".  Messing around, I stumbled on this solution: `Foo.__dict__['bar']`

Comment: @darkfeline: That isn't really right. Most seriously, what you've got there (a `builtins.classmethod` instance) isn't a method, and isn't even callable. But there are more minor issues, like the fact that this probably doesn't work with inheritance the way you expect. Why is `Foo.bar.__func__` not what you're looking for?

Comment: I see what you're saying.  `Foo.__dict__['bar']` seemed like it was getting the function directly, but after some more testing and reading up on descriptors, I see that is not the case.  Thanks for your answer, though it's a bit long-winded =)

Comment: @darkfeline: Well, I'd already written the 2.x answer, and it seemed easier to write a 3.x answer that referred to what was already there, than to rewrite it and have to say half the same stuff in a slightly different way.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, unbound class methods do exist in Python 3, albeit briefly.  When a class method is first created, as part of a class definition, the class doesn't yet exist, so the method is unbound.  Once the class actually exists, the method is bound.  In order to keep a reference to the unbound method, it must be "hidden" inside a list, dictionary, etc.; simply saving it in a class attribute isn't sufficient.

I use this to get an unbound class method, so that I can later check other objects against its type.

```py
    class _HasUnboundClassMethod(object):
        @classmethod
        def _classmethod(cls):
            pass  # pragma: no cover
        _methods = [ _classmethod ]

    _ClassMethodType = type(_HasUnboundClassMethod._methods[0])
```